# Exponential, Poisson or neither?

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have two variables in a marketing context: Advertiser spend per hour and conversions per hour. kernel density approximations of the underlying distributions look like below. Both distributions have long tails; because conversions per hour is of the form events/time, I believe that it should be modeled as a Poisson random variable. Spend per hour, however, I'm not sure; it's a continuous variable and so I'm leaning towards an exponential distribution.

Is this the right way to conceive of these distributions? Would you regard one or both of them differently?

Poisson conversions

[image: Exponential spend]

Exponential spend

[image: Poisson conversions]

Comment: If the distribution has long tails, Poisson is not a good candidate, isn't it?

Comment: Before even *looking* at it -- 1. I would not consider using unitless distributions like the Poisson family for a quantity measured in a specific unit (like \$/hr); this is pretty fundamental. $\,$ 2. I would not normally consider a Poisson for a seemingly continuous variable. $\,$  3. If you have a *binned* (interval-censored) variable, the characteristics of the binning can be important in deciding how to approach it.  $\,$ 4. I wouldn't be using KDEs for this. $\,$ 5. Why do you need a model? What are you doing with the model?